# Is the leader part of ISR list

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

If i set the `min.insync.replicas` to 1, the leader will wait for a follower to fetch this record or he will send an ack to producer considering himself one of the ISR list.

Answer (score 4):

If you set `min.insync.replicas` to 1 it is sufficient that the leader will acknowledge the receival of data. The leader will not wait for any followers to acknowledge the data.

Maybe it is worth mentioning that the `min.insync.replicas` only comes into effect when you have set your producer configuration `acks` set to `all` (or `-1`).

The minimal allowed value for `min.insync.replicas` is `1`, so even if your replication factor of the topic is set to 1 you can't get below 1.

> Is the leader part of ISR list?

Yes, the leader is part of the ISR list. You can see this when calling the command line tool `kafka-topics`. In the result you will notice that the same broker number will show up as "Leader" and in "ISR":

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic test 
Topic: test PartitionCount: 1 ReplicationFactor: 3  
Topic: test Partition: 0 Leader: 3 Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3
```

Comment: In a 3 node Kafka cluster, what would be the setting for `min.insync.replicas` to tolerate the failure of one node?

Comment: In that case you need to set it to 2.

Comment: Thats what I always thought but I get a `NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS` error. I start to think that the leader is not part of the ISR and that `min.insync.replicas=1` means leader + 1 replica = 2 nodes. 
The Kafka documentary also reads in many places as if the leader was not part of ISR. Strange...

Comment: Hi @FrVaBe, I understand where you are coming from and why this is confusing as I had the same thought initially. I did some more research and found the following sentences in the Confluent Kafka Developer training material really clear and helpful: "The description on the slide is misleading because **the ISR includes the leader as well as the caught-up followers**. The ISR is a list of the replicas - **both leader and followers** - that are identical up to a specified point called the high-water mark."

Comment: Thanks a lot! for clarification I really have to check this out (need to do some cluster failure tests anyway) - and with `min.insync.replicas=2` it should be no problem to kill a node of a 3 node cluster.